# What to study after Rudin's Functional Analysis?

Tags: soft-question, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I am aware that there are one or two questions in this vein but I am looking for specific advice pertaining to my situation.

I have completed Rudin's Functional Analysis and I'm interested in going in the Operator Theory- C* Algebras direction. Dunford & Schwartz seems like one of the only possible sequels as far as books go. However D&S is huge and I'm hoping for some advice from workers in Operator Theory & C* Algebras as to which parts of D&S are most pertinent and which papers I can start reading.

Of course, if possible I would love to start reading papers but I'm wondering if it might be a bit premature and a combination of papers and monograph might be better. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely start with Banach algebras first, though. Some C* algebra texts do not spend much time on Banach algebras and sooo much of C* theory builds on Banach algebra theory. IIRC Dixmier doesn't spend too much time, if any, on Banach algebras. C* algebras are special cases of Banach algebras so anything true about Banach algebras in general is also true about C* algebras, however C* algebras are a lot nicer which also means a lot harder/more high level theory can be developed for them vs Banach algebras. As such, some C* algebra texts sometimes jump into pretty difficult stuff very quickly.

Comment: @CameronWilliams  I would say that in order to get started with $C^*$-algebras, having read chapters 10-12 of Rudin's book is sufficient.

Comment: This is general advice. (1) Always do things different. (2) Learn LaTeX! for Math. writing. Get a Linux distro, learn GIT, create repositories, save your work. (3) Maintain a concept diary. I wish someone had told me this when I was younger. (4) Learn mind mapping. If you aren't already aware of trees, hierarchical thinking, levels upon levels within plans. (A Dune reference there.) Life is so short.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a book to learn the basic theory of operator theory and $C^*$-algebras, flip those around and start reading "$C^*$-algebras and Operator Theory"  by Gerard Murphy.

Additionally, one can read the latter chapters of Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis" for another soft introduction.  If you're a bit of a masochist, you can begin with Davidson's "$C^*$-Algebras by Example", though I'd personally recommend holding off on this book until you are familiar with the basics.

I would (again, personally) recommend holding off on reading papers until you are familiar with the basic aspects of operator algebras (functional calculi, approximate units, GNS/representation theory, etc).  These tools are often used/cited without proof, and without understanding them, it's easy to get lost.

Comment: I disagree with the "masochist" part. I do agree that Davidson's book has a higher concentration of material, but precisely because of that I find myself going back to it very often, while I rarely open Murphy's. Starting with Murphy is ok (or that can be replaced with Conway, starting from the chapter on Banach algebras), but getting acquainted with Davidson's book is likely more useful in the long term.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Hopefully my edit clarifies what I meant.  It's certainly an indispensable book, and does contain the basics of the theory, but this part is rushed in order to get to the main material.